# Can Liberty support two authentication methods within same server?

Tags: websphere, web.xml, websphere-liberty

For example I need that my Web app will support two different auth methods, for GUI it will be [OpenID](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.websphere.appserver.openidConnectClient-1.0), already configured and worked. For API it will be [Http Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) based (I guess) on `<basicRegistry>`.

How do I need to configure `web.xml` that liberty will know (if it possible at all) to which authentication method redirect user?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you can make use of the authentication filters for openID. So that it will go to openID for the specified cases in filters and use default authentication otherwise. You will define a filter in server.xml and then make use of that filter in openID configuration(server.xml too).

**Configuring Authentication Filters:**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_auth_filter.html

You can use the authentication filter to determine whether certain HTTP servlet requests are processed by certain providers.

Liberty server authentication filter uses the filter criteria that are specified in the authFilter element in the server.xml file to determine whether certain HTTP servlet requests are processed by certain providers, such as OpenID, OpenID Connect, or SPNEGO, for authentication.

**Configuring Authentication Filter for OpenId:**
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_config_rp_openid.html

*Optional: Configure the Authentication Filter.
If the providerIdentifier attribute is configured inside the openId element in the server.xml file, you can configure authFilterRef to limit the requests that should be intercepted by the OpenID provider defined by the providerIdentifier attribute.*